# printf following zeros to a certain degree

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to print zeros to a certain length to compare with another numbers which is store as string, I was wondering how to do that?

Edit: added sample code
For example:

```
printf("%s\n", "References:\n3.141592653"
    "58979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899");
printf("Monte Carlo: %d nodes over %d iterations calculated Pi as:\n%1.9f\n", numnodes, 
    final_iters,pi);    //Print the calculated value of pi
```

The out is

```
References:
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899
Monte Carlo 16 nodes over 160000 iterations calculated Pi as:
3.142025000
```

How would I make the actual calculation fill in zeros to the end of the string?

Comment: You'll need to show your code so we can see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: I don't see any code at all, much less any that tries to print anything. Can you [edit] your post to include what you've tried so far that isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

> How would I make the actual calculation fill in zeros to the end of the string?

Code could attempt various numeric approaches such as

```
printf("%1.9f%071d\n", pi, 0); // Print an extra int 0 with wide width padded with '0'
printf("%1.80f\n", pi);        // Print with wide precision - (might not all be 0's)
```

Yet I worry that specifiers with large width/precision and number specifiers may break some `printf()` implementation.  so I'll add a text approach.

```
#define PI_STR "3.1415926535" \
    "8979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899"
printf("%s\n", "References:\n" PI_STR);

// Remember length of reference pi string
int pi_ref_len = (sizeof PI_STR)  - 1;

...
// Print computed pi & return count of characters printed
int pi_compute_len = printf("%1.9f", pi);

// Use a loop or print a portion of a string "0000...000"
char zeros[sizeof PI_STR];
memset(zeros, '0', sizeof zeros);
//        v--- %s w/precision can print a non-null character terminated char array
printf("%.*s\n", pi_ref_len - pi_compute_len, zeros);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear whether you simply wanted to "print" the calculated value padded to the right to the length of your reference PI, or whether you were attempting to create a new string containing the value zero padded to the length of the original?

While you have two good answers, a blending of the two (using `sprintf` from Aneury Perez's answer) and using the length of the reference string and `memset` from [@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux)'s answer, you can create a string containing your calculated value padded to the end with zeros *without* using any *width modifiers*.

In your output, it appears you were attempting to create that result in your `pi` variable referenced as `char*` in your second `printf` statement.

You can accomplish this using `sprintf` to write your calculated value to an array sized based on your reference. (either a normal array with automatic storage type if your reference is a defined literal, or to a VLA (*Variable Length Array*) or allocated array if your reference is simply referenced by a pointer).

Since `sprintf` returns the number of characters written (excluding the null byte used to end the output of strings), there is no need to scan the resulting buffer again using `strlen`. You can then simply write, e.g. `pi_ref_len - (chars written with sprintf)` zeros to the end of the array you filled by `sprintf` beginning at an offset of `(chars written with sprintf)` from the beginning of your array.

A short example (shamelessly plagiarizing the variable names used by @chux) could be written as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PI_STR "3.1415926535" \
    "8979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899"

int main (void) {

    int pi_ref_len = (sizeof PI_STR)  - 1,
        written = 0;
    char pi_calc_str[sizeof PI_STR] = "";
    double pi_calc = 3.142025;  /* presumably returned by some calculation */

    /* write calculated value to str saving characters written */
    written = sprintf (pi_calc_str, "%lf", pi_calc);

    /* if written less than reference chars */
    if (written < pi_ref_len)   /* write that many zeros to end */
        memset (pi_calc_str + written, '0', pi_ref_len - written);

    printf ("ref: %s\nnew: %s\n", PI_STR, pi_calc_str);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/pi_fill_zeros
ref: 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899
new: 3.14202500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you. in comment the result, maybe there are better solution but this works. in `printf` the **%016** should be change to your ***max_buffer length*** or preferred range and don't forget to add 0 after %.

```
printf("%016f\n\n",3.142025000); //// 000000003.142025


 ///3.14159000000000000000000000000
 #define MAX_BUFFER 32
float pi = 3.141592653;
char digit[MAX_BUFFER]={'\0'};
sprintf(digit, "%f", pi);
int l = strlen(digit);
int dif = MAX_BUFFER-l;
 for(int i=0;i<dif;i++)
 {
     digit[i+l-1]='0';
 }
 printf("%s", digit);
```